# sqlalchemy date functions missing

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy with sqlite and python.

```
dataset.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='replace')
def query(string):
    return pd.read_sql_query(string, disk_engine)
```

Dataset is a pandas dataframe loaded from a csv file.

```
 date = "select SUBSTR(Date,1) from data LIMIT 1"
 print query(date)

                SUBSTR(Date,1)
0  2014-08-08 00:00:00.000000
```

So the SUBSTR() method does work, but when I try this :

```
date = "select YEAR(Date) from data LIMIT 1"
print query(date)

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: YEAR [SQL: 'select YEAR(Date) from data LIMIT 1']
```

I get this error.

I didn't import SUBSTR so why the SUBSTR() method is recognized and not any Date functions ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem when running tests (using sqlite) against code that has sqlalchemy running sql written for mysql syntax. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe `Year()` Is a function in sqlite.

You should use `strftime` Instead.

Something like `select strftime('%Y',date) from data limit 1`

W3 Resource on strftime.
http://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-strftime.php